# Creating Management System in a Flutter Application

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile-application

I am working on an online shopping application using the flutter platform and I am trying to create a management system so that the company's workers themselves can upload and delete products .
How can I do so ?

Comment: What are you trying to ask? the architecture? the flow? anything else?

Comment: I am trying to know how to enable the workers to control the app database by themselves without the need for me to do it from the firebase console

Comment: Sadly , I am still a beginner so I have no idea what is the difference between the architecture and the flow

Comment: Architecture is how you want to build this, Front-end, back-end & DB. Flow is how you want that app to go, from which screen to which screen. How many screens should be there? etc

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :D Actually my main problem is the back-end and DB because as flutter is somehow new there are not many available source code out there . How can handle that ?

Comment: Flutter is front-end. You have to build back-end and DB on your own. If you want both at one. Go for Firebase.

Comment: Okay I did some research on github and there is something confusing me I hope you tolerate my questions sir . Is it true that I should design two versions of the app one for the workers of the company in which they can update data about products and one for the users so they can buy products from ?

Comment: yes offcourse. One is Admin panel you can say, for the Admins like the workers of the company. And the other one is consumer portal, for the users who wants to buy.

Comment: Okay I understand now but may I ask , and it's the last question I promise , if we are going to publish the two versions on google play store , how do we prevent the users from downloading the version designed for workers . In other words , how do we hide this version from public ?

Comment: No issues, you can ask more if you want. You don't need to hide anything. You just have to set some login credentials for admin panel, like some email/password for admin, so no public can use that. Simple.

Comment: I am very thankful , the information actually helped me a lot :D

Comment: My pleasure. I have put all of that in below answer. Please accept that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ask about **Architecture** or **Flow**. Let me tell you.

- **Architecture** is how you want to build the app. Most Commonly used architecture is 3-tier Architecture i.e. **Front-end, back-end & DB.**
- **Flow** is how you want that app to move, from which screen to which screen. What will be the starting screen? What will be next routes from that screen? How many screens should be there? etc

As Flutter is Front-end. You have to build back-end and DB on your own. If you want both at once. Go for **[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/).**

As far as Some Management System App is concern, you have to build two apps for that. One is **Admin Portal**, second one is **Consumer Portal**.

- **Admin Portal** is for the admins, who are actually owner of that app, or that system. They have rights to add, edit or delete anything on the app.
- **Consumer Portal** is for the users, who gonna use that app. They have rights to view only, or they can add a request to add or some edition to the admin.

**How to differentiate between them? How to hide Admin portal from consumers?**

You don't need to hide anything. You just have to set some login credentials for Admin Portal, like some email/password for only Admin, so no public can use that. Simple!